# How do I display avg throughput time in Grafana (prometheus) in a correct way?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-templating

I have a java application running and I want to display the avg throughput time in Grafana.

I have this metric:

```
avg by (pod) ((increase(application_throughput_seconds_sum{service="$service"}[1m])) / (increase(application_throughput_seconds_count{service="$service"}[1m])))
```

While it does show the correct number of the tests that I'm running, it just only shows the dots:

[image]

The two stripes that you see were the moments I did a small load test to calculate it. I would actually like to have a constant line and when there is no load it just shows 0.

Do I need to change the query or is it something else in Grafana that I have to change?